# PFUser currentUser returns nil

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform, pfuser

I'm using Parse SDK, login and signup are working perfectly : `[PFUser currentUser]` is returning the current user.

But after restarting app, `[PFUser currentUser]` is returning nil.

Why is the application not persisting the session ?

Login code (from parse.com) I'm using :

```
[PFUser logInWithUsernameInBackground:self.username.text password:self.password.text
                                block:^(PFUser *user, NSError *error) {
                                    if (user) {
                                        // Do stuff after successful login.
                                        } else {
                                        // The login failed. Check error to see why.
                                    }
                                }];
```

**EDIT 2: Create new project, it works. I don't know how and why, but it works.**

EDIT: There is no `logout`in the whole project

[image]

Comment: Are u sure u are not calling logout somewhere

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Yes, I am.

Comment: In that case it will always return nil after logging out

Comment: I'm sure I'm not using logout I meant

Comment: Where are you calling `logIn..InBackground`?

Comment: in `- (IBAction)loginAction:(id)sender { ... }` in custom loginViewController

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are calling `.logout` somewhere, in which case the app will return `nil` for `[PFUser currentUser]`.

The current user will persist from session to session if you do not automatically log out the user.

Comment: No, there is no `logout` in the whole project :( I've not implemented this functionality for the moment !

Comment: Are you running the app in the simulator?

Comment: Yes and in my iPhone, same result.

Comment: There's another possibility - you're using the 'Stop' button on Xcode to end the project, which doesn't give the app a chance to save the login locally. Try running the app on the simulator, then exiting the app with a simulated tap of the home button (command + shift + H) to allow the app a normal close. Then press Stop, then press Run again in Xcode.

Answer (score 0):

```
PFUser *currentUser = [PFUser currentUser];
if (currentUser) {
    //save the installation
    PFInstallation *currentInstallation = [PFInstallation currentInstallation];
    currentInstallation[@"installationUser"] = [[PFUser currentUser]objectId];
    // here we add a column to the installation table and store the current user’s ID
    // this way we can target specific users later

    // while we’re at it, this is a good place to reset our app’s badge count
    // you have to do this locally as well as on the parse server by updating
    // the PFInstallation object
    }
```